# Automatically (protect or update or retain) a cell's formula when a row is added from "Zapier and Twilio"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

When a row is added in this case from a (Zapier into a Google sheet, the formula in a cell not used by the incoming data is deleted.

How can I retain/protect the original formula in column **AE** being `=IF( $Y:$Y ,,$C:$C)` or automatically update it from the previous row, when the zap inserts a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drop your **`IF`** formula ( **`=IF( $Y:$Y ,,$C:$C)`** ) and use **`ARRAYFORMULA`** variant:

**`={"arrayformula here"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($Y2:$Y, , $C2:$C))}`**

[image]

Comment: That is awesome... it works perfectly, much appreciated...